# Convert text into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have text in following format. But I want to convert into dict. I'm using this code to convert into dict. But it is not working.

```
dict( (n,int(v)) for n,v in (a.split('=') for a in string.split() ) )
```

Please anybody help me? thanks

```
 name = Kurradu
 image =
 image_size =
 producer = P. Kiran
 writer =
 starring = Varun Sandesh,Neha Sharma
 music = Achu
 cinematography = Sarvesh Murari
 editing =
 distributor =
 released = 12 November 2009
 studio =
 country = IND
```

Comment: do you get any error? please precise `is not working`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hours ago you needed just a list and now you need a dict?

```
text = """ name = Kurradu
 image =
 image_size =
 producer = P. Kiran
 writer =
 starring = Varun Sandesh,Neha Sharma
 music = Achu
 cinematography = Sarvesh Murari
 editing =
 distributor =
 released = 12 November 2009
 studio =
 country = IND"""


d = dict(map(str.strip, line.split('=', 1)) for line in text.splitlines())


# d is now:

{'cinematography': 'Sarvesh Murari',
 'country': 'IND',
 'distributor': '',
 'editing': '',
 'image': '',
 'image_size': '',
 'music': 'Achu',
 'name': 'Kurradu',
 'producer': 'P. Kiran',
 'released': '12 November 2009',
 'starring': 'Varun Sandesh,Neha Sharma',
 'studio': '',
 'writer': ''}
```

Comment: thank for help. Why I'm getting this `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #11 has length 3; 2 is required`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
dict(a.split('=') for a in string.split('\n'))
```

`int(v)` isn't going to work, because the values on the right side of the `=` cannot be converted to int